# Как проверять пустой ли ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Имеется `ArrayList` и нужно проверять пустой ли он. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
if(arrayList.getSize() == 0){
    //пустой
} else {
    //НЕ пустой
}
```

Или так:

```
if(arrayList.isEmpty()){
    //пустой
} else {
    //НЕ пустой
}
```